# libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, package

I'm newbie in rails and I'm working on Ubuntu 19.10 yesterday I decide to upgrade my OS to new version every things is going fine after upgrading finished after t i start to use my computer to develop that found any rails command not works and showed me this error

```
in `require': libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/ace/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.so (LoadError)
```

I found people with same issues but none of them have problem in rails and any of them is useful for me .

I think the problem is about libffi.so.6 package because ffi-1.13.1 is installed on my OS

Comment: you can try this answer : [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875869/ubuntu-20-04-upgrade-python-missing-libffi-so-6)
it working with me.

Comment: @ThinhNguyen Thanks Dude it solve my problem, add your comment as answer to set this answer useful

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 upgraded libffi6 to libffi7 but your Rails apps are still looking for libffi6.
You need to run the following command:

```
gem pristine ffi
```

This should fix it

Comment: `Failed to find gems ["ffi"] >= 0` (on CircleCI)

Answer (score 5):

`gem pristine ffi` did not help for me. The more invasive

```
gem uninstall ffi
gem install ffi
```

did the job.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `gem "ffi", github: "ffi/ffi"` to my `Gemfile` fixed it

Comment: The GitHub part might not be valid anymore. I got this error when installing the gem: 
fatal: not a git repository: 'ext/ffi_c/libffi/.git'

Answer (score 0):

1. it requires you to rebuild when you switch rubies.
2. Annoyingly, it seems like it also seems to fail into this message even when installed and you also try to use `byebug` debugger. (It does this for me even when the ffi binary is otherwise installed-- and taking out the `byebug` debugger does not fall into this ffi error)

Using `ruby/debug` seems to work

Answer (score 0):

My error was `libffi 8` on `ubuntu 20.04` for `rails 6.1.4`

https://github.com/ffi/ffi#requirements solved my issue

```
--enable-system-libffi : Force usage of system libffi
--disable-system-libffi : Force usage of builtin libffi
--enable-libffi-alloc : Force closure allocation by libffi
--disable-libffi-alloc : Force closure allocation by builtin method
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/947#issuecomment-1089299217

First uninstall the gem:

`gem uninstall ffi`

then reinstall it with:

`gem install ffi -- --disable-system-libffi`

Answer (score -1):

Here's what helped me:

1. Drop your project's vendor/cache folder
2. `bundle install`